# JQuery Datatables get the number of rows to display and the current page number

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the jQuery Datatables component and I need to retrieve the number of rows to display and the current page number.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to access this data programmatically for an existing DataTable? If so, use [`page.info()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info())

Comment: Related: [jQuery dataTables page info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32410133/12567365) - and probably other similar questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
to retrieve the current page number:

```
var table = $(id_table).DataTable();
var numPage= table.page();
```

to go to a specific page:

```
table.page(numPage).draw(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

datatable is very simple ,

1. call jquery.dataTables.min.js and jquery.dataTables.min.css
2. then datatable function in jquery call like below,

   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#table_first_last_numbers').DataTable({

   ```
    data: tableData,
    columns: columnData,
    pageLength: 4,
    pagingType: "first_last_numbers"
   ```

   });
   });